# Multiple Context.Forward calls gives exception "execution finished with multiple resume handlers specified through IDialogStack"

Tags: botframework

I am inside a dialog called as "ParentCustSvcDialog", called from within the "RootDialog". Within this dialog, I am trying to forward the call to LUIS.

Based on what LUIS responds, I am forwarding a call to QnAMaker. I would like to keep this conditional logic within the parent dialog.

However, the conversation does not get through and the call to QnAMaker, and gives exception as below:

> Exception: IDialog method execution finished with multiple resume handlers specified through IDialogStack

I pasted the code below. Any idea where is the issue?

### ParentCustSvcDialog.cs

```
    LuisDialogCustomResult luisDialogCustomResult = null;
    QnAMakerDialogCustomResult qnAMakerDialogCustomResult = null;

    private async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
            await context.Forward<LuisDialogCustomResult>(new LuisLeavesDialog(), ResumeAfterLuisDoneDialog, context.Activity.AsMessageActivity());
            if (null == luisDialogCustomResult.MainIntent)  // No meaningful response from LUIS
            {
                // POST to the QnA Maker via the QnA Maker Dialog
                await context.Forward<QnAMakerDialogCustomResult>(new QnAMakerLeavesDialog(), ResumeAfterQnAMakerDoneDialog, context.Activity.AsMessageActivity());
            }
            else    // Meaningful Response from LUIS.
            {   
                await context.PostAsync($"(DEBUG:LUIS) Here is what I found: </br> { customMessage }");
            }

            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    private async Task ResumeAfterLuisDoneDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<LuisDialogCustomResult> result)
    {
        // Control Comes to Parent Dialog once done with Luis Portion
        luisDialogCustomResult = (await result as LuisDialogCustomResult);
    }

    private async Task ResumeAfterQnAMakerDoneDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<QnAMakerDialogCustomResult> result)
    {
        // Control Comes to Parent Dialog once done with QnA Portion
        qnAMakerDialogCustomResult = await result as QnAMakerDialogCustomResult;
    }
```

Comment: You should add more details about your initial dialog (`RootDialog`) and more content of your ParentCustSvcDialog for us to help

Comment: Hi and thanks for responding, Nicolas.
There is nothing more really to the ParentCustSvcDialog.cs code.  The RooDialog just does a Context.call for the first time when a user request comes in to the bot. Thereon, it waits on the ParentCustSvcDialog - MessageReceived() context. When next message comes in, it is first sent to LUIS. Depending upon what LUIS responds(LUIS Call exits with ResumeAfterLuisDoneDialog() resume function), it then subsequently forwards the call to  QnA Maker which exits at ResumeAfterQnAMakerDoneDialog(). So, technically there is one exit point at any point of time.

Comment: If you provide all your code when can quickly replay it on our side, and also maybe see some things that can cause the error and you had not seen. Right now I can't spend too much time on your case trying to guess what is you exact implementation, hence I'm asking for the code as the problem is not directly visible

Comment: Hi Nicholas R - I could fix the issue. More than one context.forward() calls, one after the other within the same Dialog state listener viz.: MessageReceived(), seems to cause this. So, I moved the second context.forward() call into the Resume function callback meant for the first context.forward entrant, once finishes its task by calling context.Done(). Thanks for your help and time! Appreciate it.

Comment: From the code on top, I had to pull out the below line from the MessageReceived() routine and put it into the ResumeAfterLuisDoneDialog() callback function and perform conditional checks therein:
await context.Forward<QnAMakerDialogCustomResult>(new QnAMakerLeavesDialog(), ResumeAfterQnAMakerDoneDialog, context.Activity.AsMessageActivity());

Thanks, for your help and time!

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. as the exceptions say, when your bot is looking at the code it says multiple ways to go forward through the code.

Your guiding the waterfall to multiple points, which basically means you have an architectural problem. 
Try to keep up the waterfall model nd keep the bot to exit through only one point at a time.

**Bot framework does not like multiple endpoints for the same IDialog.**

You can limit it by changing the way you are looking into the problem you are trying to solve.

todo:

1. Remove multiple exit points for the code.
2. If you need
   multiple, Have them differentiated in such a way that only one shows up at a time.
3. Always make the architecture in such a way that the waterfall model is followed.

Comment: Thanks for that, Alok!
I have also tried to put some comments above to a response from Nicolas.
I understand the waterfall approach that you are talking about. If you see the code, the second Context.forward to QnA maker is "Conditional" and happens only when the first exit is completed by the LUIS call. So, technically, I am not defining multiple exit points for the same IDialog implementation. Also, the exception seems to occur at the end of all calls and not within any of the Exit Resume methods.

Comment: It's is basically because you have 2 possible climaxes for your code.

Comment: Hi Alok. I fixed this. Added a comment on top to the response sent by Nicholas. Thanks for your help and time!